# How to link a textbox or label to a combobox value? I found a way to link to a number value but not a text value

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word, textbox, userform

I'm linking a selected combobox value to a label as a "Control Tip Text" It worked when the Combobox value was a number. but not when it's a text.

There is the code that worked on top, and the lower code is what I'm trying to do.

What am I missing?

[image: Userform Image Click Here]

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

   If ComboBox1.Value = (0.032) Then Label2 = "test"
   If ComboBox1.Value = (0.02) Then Label2 = "run"

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

   If ComboBox1.Value = (THK) Then Label2 = "test"
   If ComboBox1.Value = (DIA) Then Label2 = "run"

End Sub
```

I would like to have a different text show in the textbox or label for each item in my combobox array.

Comment: DIA is a string, so it must be in quotes. The brackets are not necessary. ComboBox1.Value = "DIA"

Comment: John, That did it! Thank you so much.